# Vim autocmd error

Tags: vim

I have this script to set variables when loading Python files

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
```

When I load a Python file I get this error:

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*.py":
E518: Unknown option: set
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: it looks like what you really want is the `Filetype` event rather than `BufNewFile` and `BufRead`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.test set tabstop=4 
      \softtabstop=4 
      \shiftwidth=4  
      \textwidth=790  
      \expandtab  
      \autoindent  
      \fileformat=unix
```

or

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.test set tabstop=4|set softtabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set textwidth=79 |set expandtab|set autoindent|set fileformat=unix
```

or

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.test set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4  textwidth=79 expandtab autoindent fileformat=unix
```

Comment: Cool, just didn't need the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The following are a couple of ways of achieving what you want :

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=79 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix
```

OR

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ softtabstop=4
    \ shiftwidth=4
    \ textwidth=79
    \ expandtab
    \ autoindent
    \ fileformat=unix
```

> **Explanation** :
>
> In your autocommand you're calling the `:set` (:h :set) command which
>   is used to set vim options. If you want to set multiple options, you
>   can either call `:set` with multiple options separated with whitespace
>   or call `:set` multiple times for each option, separating each `:set`
>   command with the `|` (:h :bar).
>
> **Tip** :
>
> Since your objective is to define certain options specifically for
>   python files, you should either use `:autocmd Filetype python ...` for
>   this, or better yet create a `ftplugin/python/custom.vim` file where
>   you can enable these settings using the `:setlocal` command as opposed
>   to `:set` to set them only for the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do *.*  instead of *.test and it works for me.
(Astrix . Astrix )

Example:
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.* set tabstop=4